# Cannot recover key while making signed apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-keystore

I am facing an issue while making a signed apk, it keep on saying **cannot recover key**.
Keystore is working fine, it is generating SHA keys and showing key alias as well, when I enter wrong password it shows **wrong verification code**. 
Signed apk get generated when I make new keystore, but I want to update my app on Google play using the same keystore.

I am stuck in it please help me out of it.

Comment: @intellJ my friend told me that your password may wrong, in that case I do this for just verification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long time searching on the internet, I found a solution to my problem which did the trick.

```
keytool -storepasswd -new [insert new keystore password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]

keytool -keypasswd -alias [insert alias] -new [insert new key password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]
```

I just change the password of my **KeyStore** and **KeyAlias** and suddenly it generates the signed apk for me.

Comment: is there any way we can recover the jks password in android studio 3

Comment: What if you don't have Java JDK (for example because of Oracle greed)? Now I know: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Comment: My both passwords are the same, still in Android Studio 3.3 - Cannot recover key.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I just don't get it... the terminal recognizes old password but android studio no

Comment: Are they pushing us to use app bundle or what!!
This worked .. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a known bug on Android Studio 4.2 any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Play App signing enabled, you can ask Google to generate a new key for you and use that. Seems a good practice to follow.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

Please enter correct Key store password, Key alias , Key password when we generated signed apk before sometimes.If we enter wrong or doing some mistake to generate signed apk we getting this type of the error